# [Ionic 2]How to make the app in browser use Android material design all time

Tags: ionic-framework, material-design, ionic2

I want to use the Ionic 2 app I build as web app (progressive web app). But I want to when build, it will ONLY use android material design. Right now in localhost by running Ionic serve, the result on my browser is random - sometimes it looks like Apple with tabs at the bottom, and sometimes it looks Android with tab up top.

How can I build the app to make sure the output www folder will ONLY use Android style. And I can deploy the build as a website (run on desktop with no Cordova stuffs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the `mode` prop in the config options when you bootstrap your app in `app.ts`:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [SomeProviders], {mode: 'md'});
```

Comment: There is no mode: 'md' in the config document here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/ But this is working! Many thanks!!

Comment: No problem. I will be sending a PR soon to add it.